# The 39 steps movie script

Tags: cinema

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTK8c69c1fE#t=38m27s

Hi. Would somebody be able to tell what the daughter is saying around "we've been all to church and the sermon lasted for oooo "  (oooo part)

I searched for the script but all the scripts I found are different from the actual movie dialogue.

Comment: 100 answers to this question will all say the same thing(perhaps!!) - "three quarters of an hour".

Answer (score 1):

She says it lasted "three-quarters of an hour", meaning 45 minutes.

Comment: You English speakers are all awesome. How do you say like that and how do you understand these.. To me it sounds like " Thee quadus Anah " And I know that's why I suck at English :)

Comment: @megaboy1 Part of the issue is that she has a Northeastern sort of [non-rhotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents) accent.  Another part is that the audio and video aren't in sync, which may have helped you more than you might imagine.

Comment: That rhotic wiki page is great! I never knew the rule clearly..Appreciated!

Comment: You're very welcome.  You can upvote (or downvote) either answer with the up/down arrows, and accept one of them by clicking the check mark outline.

Answer (score 1):

She says:

> The sermon lasted for three quarters of an hour.

She says it really quickly, making the word *quarters* almost monosyllabic :)

Comment: You English speakers are all awesome. How do you say like that and how do you understand these.. To me it sounds like " Thee quadus Anah " And I know that's why I suck at English :)

Comment: @megaboy1: As a matter of fact, I am not a native English speaker and have never lived in an English speaking country. It's just a matter of exposure to the language. Watch more movies :)

Comment: So what's your secret.. watching a lot of movies? and what country are you living in ?

Comment: My secret... I dunno, I read a lot, and watch movies a lot. I live in Armenia

Comment: That's great. I will just do that..

Comment: The funny thing is that you if you had asked "What does 'Thee quadus Anah' mean in English?" I'm pretty sure I could have told you, based just on that phonetic spelling. That's essentially how I'd pronounce this phrase in normal conversation.

Comment: @megaboy1, when you say "I will do just that" I assume you mean that you're moving to Aermenia?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel, Yes of course indeed I meant that, doctor.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill, great to know!